# I want to actually show the HTML comment code

Tags: html, comments

I want the output in my window to show the actual `"<!-- -->"`.  How do I quote that so it prints out?
Same for printing out `<h2>Text Here</h2>` - I want it to actually print that out, and not do the `<h2>` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1: Escape characters (recommended option)

---

`&lt;` is <

`&gt;` is >

Have a look at this code snippet:

```html
This will appear as a comment:
<br><!-- Test -->
<br>
<br>This will actually appear:
<br>&lt;!-- Test --&gt;
```

You can find out how to escape characters here: https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

### Method 2: Use the `xmp` tag

---

**Warning:** this feature is discouraged by MDN webdocs:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

```html
This will appear as a comment:
<br><!-- Test -->
<br>
<br>This will actually appear:
<br><xmp><!-- Test --></xmp>
```

Comment: the &lt; and &gt; worked perfectly! thanks

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked!

Comment: @mplungjan When I began writing my question, there were no answers here, so I didn't copy you! It can happen that several people give the same answer – there are only so many solutions out there, and these are the only two that I can think of.